# Lost with Nano and i2c

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c

I've been struggling with some code that was failing to "begin()" any devices on my i2c bus. I've uploaded a scanner program from arduino playground which lists the addresses of any i2c modules found.  With a single sensor connected the whole arduino freezes but when I unplug the wires from the a4 and a5 pins it continues. Plug them back on and it locks. I've tried with the SDA / SCL wires reversed as I've seen mention of things being backward.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe missing pull-ups?

Comment: So I've watched a video on pullups and what they do but I can't find anything about specifically what I need to do on the Nano. Am I using internal pullups on the 5v pin connecting the I2C devices or am I changing something on A4 or A5?

Comment: I don't know if the nano has internal pullups, just try adding extra 4k7 as it's a simple thing to do

Comment: If it still freezes, determine the voltage on scl in a stucked state. If possible, monitor scl with an oscilloskope

Comment: Sorry, my electronics knowledge is limited let alone integrating with microcontrollers.So far I've managed to build this device with all my modules plugging straight onto sda/ scl and voltage pins with little theory required. What do I connect with the 4.7k ohm resisotor to, is it between the voltage pin (in this case 3.3v) and SCL?

Comment: Yes, you connect one resistor between sda and vcc, the other between scl and vcc

Comment: can you please share the code

Comment: As I remember, the Arduino Nano runs with 5V, so why do you write about 3.3V. Does the device work with 3.3V? You cannot simply mix different supply voltages

Comment: @chrisl I have 5 devices connected to the Uno. One requires a minimum of 5V, the others are on the 3.3V and all are working.

Comment: @Vaibhav Any code where I try to run .begin directly on devices type instances fails regardless of which device I have connected. But the current code where I'm trying to scanning for whatever is connected and display the address of the devices is from here https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/

Comment: @StephenYork OK can you share the schematic of your project.

Comment: @Vaibhav How will a schematic help? Like I said I had a single sensor connected...I I have the nano plugged into a breadboard with pin terminals off the A4 (SDA) and A5 (SCL) pins and pins terminals off the 3v and gnd pins.  I then plug my TSL2591 onto those terminals, VIN to the 3v, GND to GND, SDA to SDA, SCL to SCL. When I run the scanner it locks up. When I disconnected the SDA and SCL it continues running. This is identical wiring to how it was on the Uno. Why on the Uno do I not need pull up resistors yet on the nano it seems I do? As I understand it they're the same core hardware

Comment: @StephenYork actually it doesn't about nano or UNO. Unlike UART or SPI connections, the I2C bus drivers are "open drain", meaning that they can pull the corresponding signal line low, but cannot drive it high. Thus, there can be no bus contention where one device is trying to drive the line high while another tries to pull it low, eliminating the potential for damage to the drivers or excessive power dissipation in the system. They might be internally pulled up in hardware or you need to do it externally.

Comment: did you test the pins with digitalWrite?

Comment: I give up, people just keep asking bogus questions over and over. This is clearly not a valuable forum to ask anything on. I literally cannot make it any clearer. NO I didn't test digital write, my code works on the uno, not on nano... so why given it's the same chip and everything's connected the same with the same code?